# Python: If array contains duplicate, edit string to (howmanyduplicates)item

Tags: python-3.x

Context: Inventory system for Python Text RPG.

How can I have python detect if there is a duplicate in a array during appending a value, and change that string?

For example: if I append `pencil` to `items` and `pencil` is already found, have it change that string to `items=['pencil x2']`.

Here is a relevant slice of my program:

```
items = ['pencil'];
def appendloot(whatloot):
  items.append(whatloot);
appendloot('pencil')

def printitems():
  myitems=", ".join(str(i) for i in items)
  print(myitems)
printitems()
```

It's showing it as `pencil,pencil`, but I want it to show as `pencil x2`.

clarification edit: if `items` has 5 pencils, it should print pencils x5.

Comment: It may be better to create a dictionary of items and store the item count. The code will be easier to maintain. You can also use a list of tuples: `[('gold', 100), ('pencil', 2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just add an if statement in the appending function

```
items = ['pencil']
def appendloot(whatloot):
    if whatloot in items:
        items[items.index(whatloot)] = f"{whatloot} x2"
    else:
        items.append(whatloot)
```

dictionary approach:

```
items = {'pencil':1}

def appendloot(whatloot, amount):
    if whatloot in items.keys():
        items[whatloot] += amount
    else:
        items[whatloot] = amount

appendloot('pencil',3)
appendloot('9mm ammo', 30)
appendloot('baseball bat',1)

for i in items.keys():
    print(f"{i}", f"x{items[i]}")
```

ill leave the counting part to you if you want to use the list approach, so you have a little challenge :)

Comment: I want the number following `x` to be the count of how many duplicates. so if there are 5 pencils in `items`, it should print pencils x5.

Comment: like I said I want to leave you a little challenge, counting in lists is critical python basics. if you want ill add a dictionary approach

Comment: sure, as you can tell i'm new to Python.

Comment: thanks for your time and effort, really appreciate it.